# CSS - buttons don't align properly

Tags: html, css

No matter what I do (for a few hours now) I cannot align `<div class="kafelek">` next to each other; the code currently looks like this:

```css
body {
  background-color: #003C3D;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #C3CECB;
}

#headerlogo {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  animation: slide-in 1s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes slide-in {
  from {
    top: -100px;
  }
  to {
    top: 20px;
  }
}

.pre1 {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #C3CECB;
  float: left;
}

.pre2 {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #C3CECB;
  float: right;
}

.alignkafel1,
.alignkafel2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.kolumna {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  color: #C3CECB;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.kolumna:first-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.kolumna:last-child {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .kolumna {
    width: 100%;
    align-content: center;
  }
}

kolumna2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  color: #C3CECB;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.kolumna2:first-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.kolumna2:last-child {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .kolumna2 {
    width: 100%;
    align-content: center;
  }
}

.kafelek {
  background-color: #006D57;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #C3CECB;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .kafelek {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}

.kafelek:hover {
  border: 2px solid #7EDF00;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img src="" img id="headerlogo" />
  <br /> <br /> Centrum zgłoszeniowe AOK
</div>

<div class="pre1"> Delivery Support </div>
<div class="pre2"> Middle Mile</div>



<div class="alignkafel1">
  <div class="kafelek">Koszta Dodatkowe</div>
  <div class="kafelek">COMING SOON</div>
  <div class="kafelek">COMING SOON</div>
  <div class="kafelek">COMING SOON</div>
</div>

<div class="alignkafel2">
  <div class="kafelek">COMING SOON</div>
  <div class="kafelek">COMING SOON</div>
  <div class="kafelek">COMING SOON</div>
  <div class="kafelek">COMING SOON</div>
</div>
```

I've been trying with multiple options but everything gets messed up in the end.

It looks like this:
[Messed up website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ql8c6.png)

And I want each of the 8 `.kafelek` (which are the buttons) to be perfectly aligned in 1 row with each other and also properly centered to align with .pre1 and .pre2

Please help ;-;

Comment: your `.alignkafel1` flex container has zero width. You can quickly attempt to solve it just giving it `width: 100%` but maybe there are some other layout problems

Comment: I basically fixed it like that

And it does work, but the buttons aren't centered properly.

Answer (score 1):

The container for the buttons has a width of 0 which prevents the flexbox from working properly. Adding a width fixes the problem.

```
.alignkafel1,
.alignkafel2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I have added a width of `60%` to align the buttons roughly to the `pre` above. Currently the `pre` have `float` property set. Ideally, you want a parent container to enforce the boundaries of your page content and refrain from using `float` css property.

Comment: All the buttons got stacked in 1 vertical row

Comment: All the buttons are stacked in a single horizontal row. Is that the behavior you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

In alignkafel1&2 set align-items and justify content properties to control the alignment of your buttons which are the flex items.

Answer (score 0):

I removed `.alignkafel1` and `.alignkafel2` classes and replaced them with a single `.alignkafel` class with CSS `Flex`. The `flex-direction: row` property is used for `.alignkafel` class to give the desired layout. I additionally removed the unused CSS classes from the code.

**You can see the following example:**

```css
body {
  background-color: #003C3D;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #C3CECB;
}

#headerlogo {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  animation: slide-in 1s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes slide-in {
  from {
    top: -100px;
  }
  to {
    top: 20px;
  }
}

.pre1 {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #C3CECB;
  float: left;
}

.pre2 {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #C3CECB;
  float: right;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.kafelek {
  background-color: #006D57;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #C3CECB;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.kafelek:nth-child(4) {
  margin-right: 100px !important;
}

.kafelek:nth-child(5) {
  margin-left: 100px !important;
}
.kafelek:hover {
  border: 2px solid #7EDF00;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.alignkafel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img src="" img id="headerlogo" />
  <br /> <br /> Centrum zgłoszeniowe AOK
</div>

<div class="pre1"> Delivery Support </div>
<div class="pre2"> Middle Mile</div>



<div class="alignkafel">
  <div class="kafelek">Koszta Dodatkowe</div>
  <div class="kafelek">COMING SOON</div>
  <div class="kafelek">COMING SOON</div>
  <div class="kafelek">COMING SOON</div>
  <div class="kafelek">COMING SOON</div>
  <div class="kafelek">COMING SOON</div>
  <div class="kafelek">COMING SOON</div>
  <div class="kafelek">COMING SOON</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work - check out the code snippet

Comment: @FrancisPhant0m Thanks, I changed the code now, check again please!

Comment: Looks much better, but the buttons got centered relative to the entire website and I basically want .pre1 and .pre2 to slash the webpage in two parts and center the buttons so that there's 4 of them for each .pre1 (left and right, but centered to .pre)

Comment: @FrancisPhant0m I updated the code, it should work now.

Comment: AWESOME! 
Any idea how can I make them stack on top of another in rows when browser is resized? I also want this to appear nice on small screen

Comment: @FrancisPhant0m You'll need to use CSS media query to achieve this on different screen sizes. Then depending on the screen size can apply required CSS.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed your code, just paste it in your html and css file and everything will work fine. :D

```
<div class="header">
    <img src="" img id="headerlogo" />
    <br /> <br /> Centrum zgłoszeniowe AOK
  </div>
  
  <div class="pre1"> 
    <p>Delivery Support </p>


    <div class="alignkafel">
        <div class="kafelek">Koszta Dodatkowe</div>
        <div class="kafelek">COMING SOON</div>
        <div class="kafelek">COMING SOON</div>
        <div class="kafelek">COMING SOON</div>
      </div>


  </div>
  <div class="pre2"> 
    </p>Middle Mile</p>


    <div class="alignkafel">
        <div class="kafelek">COMING SOON</div>
        <div class="kafelek">COMING SOON</div>
        <div class="kafelek">COMING SOON</div>
        <div class="kafelek">COMING SOON</div>
      </div>
</div>





    body {
  background-color: #003C3D;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #C3CECB;
}

#headerlogo {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  animation: slide-in 1s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes slide-in {
  from {
    top: -100px;
  }
  to {
    top: 20px;
  }
}

.pre1 {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #C3CECB;
  float: left;
}

.pre2 {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #C3CECB;
  float: right;
}

.alignkafel {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.kolumna {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  color: #C3CECB;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.kolumna:first-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.kolumna:last-child {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .kolumna {
    width: 100%;
    align-content: center;
  }
}

.kolumna2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  color: #C3CECB;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.kolumna2:first-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.kolumna2:last-child {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .kolumna2 {
    width: 100%;
    align-content: center;
  }
}

.kafelek {
  background-color: #006D57;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #C3CECB;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .kafelek {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}

.kafelek:hover {
  border: 2px solid #7EDF00;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: WHOAH! Even better than I expected. 
Thanks a lot, mate!